# могло быть заменить на могло последовать

Tags: вопрос

"Обстоятельства, следствием возникновения которых могло последовать убийство".
Я так написал уже, но режет слух. Вообще это ошибка или не существенно?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка. И дело не в тавтологии.

*следствием которых могло последовать* || Здесь "быть" или "стать" требуется по смыслу, а не "последовать" — оно не подходит.

Некорректно это сочетание: *могло последовать (чем?) следствием*.
Согласно словарям, управление глагола "последовать" должно быть "за кем-чем?" или "после кого-чего?", а не "чем?". Ещё можно последовать "чему?" [совету], но это уже другое значение.

Вообще, очень закрученная фраза. Не стоит так выражаться. "Возникновения" можно убрать. Смысл от этого не меняется.

Answer (score 1):

Это грубая речевая **ошибка**.

*Тавтологии* в строгом смысле здесь *нет*, поскольку имеющиеся однокоренные слова существенно различаются по смыслу: "*следствие*" выражает **причинную связь**, в то время как "*последовать*" выражает **очередность** во времени (более позднее появление).

Основная проблема состоит в неправильном выборе глагола в ситуации логического *отождествления* одного существительного (*следствие*) с другим (*убийство*) - могло или не могло *убийство* **стать** *следствием* упомянутых обстоятельств. Выбор глаголов, подходящих для такого отождествления, весьма ограничен (**оказаться**, **быть** и т. п.), и глагол "последовать" в какую-либо логику не вписывается, поскольку даже исправление предложной сочетаемости (последовать **за** чем) приводит к бессмыслице: "убийство последовало за следствием чего-то ещё (обстоятельств)"?

Answer (score 0):

Это тавтология: "следствием последовать". Не ошибка, но стилистическая небрежность, её лучше избегать.

Answer (score 0):

Во фразе нет логических проблем. Она эквивалентна

```
Убийство могло последовать как результат тех самых обстоятельств. 
Однако убийства не последовало, хотя обстоятельства имели место.
```

А глагол можно брать вообще любой! От него ничего не зависит

```
Убийства могли процветать как результат тех самых обстоятельств. 
Убийство могло одобряться как результат тех самых обстоятельств.
```

Переход в творительный падеж неестественен в плане благозвучия и громоздкий, но в плане логики языка это обычный прием

```
Результатом тех самых обстоятельств могло одобряться даже убийство.
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127264/discussion-on-answer-by-user190920------).